# Unexpected output found while executing sudo command

Tags: java, linux, sudo

When I execute the following command in the terminal, it executes as expected i.e. it displays the current folder contents.

```
echo <password> | sudo -u root -S ls
```

But if i execute the same command in my java application, its output is:

```
<password> | sudo -u root -S ls
```

How do I overcome this?

Comment: java does not execute processes using a shell, and you are using shell metacharacters `'|'`.  there are numerous answers already on SO and the web specifying how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to execute `sh -c "echo sanovi | sudo -u root -S ls"` instead?

Comment: @FabianHenze I tried ur suggestion. But no success. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute it in the shell, the shell splits the command line according to normal shell rules, i.e. you get "execute `echo` with parameter `<password>`, pipe the result to `sudo` ...".

Java doesn't use the shell, so you're getting "execute `echo` with parameter `<password> | sudo -u root -S ls`".